# How to search data from a Elasticsearch, using spring boot with Java high level rest client?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I manually created an index named as callsearch. I got all the data from the Elasticsearch index, but now I am trying to do the specific key and value search. I tried using match query, but it returns all data whereas I am searching by specific ids.

Anyone please help me, thanks in advance. I have screenshot but I don't have a amount of reputation to add it here.

Comment: can you share the code you tried

Answer (score 0):

```
QueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("field", field)
                .fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO)
                .prefixLength(2)
                .maxExpansions(10);
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        sourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
        sourceBuilder.from(0);
        sourceBuilder.size(5);
        sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```